# Newtonsoft Json List serialization returns $id

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I'm developping an API in C# which uses Newtonsoft.Json to serialize the C# class to json and i have a really strange behavior with the serialization of the class bellow 'GetInputStatesResponse' with the following method

`JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response)`

```
public class GetInputStatesResponse     
{
    public List<InputKeyValue> InputStates { get; set; } = new List<InputKeyValue>();
}
    
public class InputKeyValue 
{   
    public InputKey Key { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

The InputKey property is an Enum.

When i serialize a 'GetInputStatesResponse i get the following Json :

```
{
  "InputStates":[
    {"$id":"1"},
    {"$id":"2"}
  ]
}
```

I thought that i should get something more like this :

```
{
  "InputStates": [  
    { Key:"Safe_Closed", Value: 0 },
    { Key:"GateFront_Closed", Value: 1 }
  ]
}
```

Any idea of the reason why i don't get the correct serialization output ?

Comment: you didn't put the most important part of your code to see what your problem is!! Please put the part that you serialize the data

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that the InputKeyValue class was inheriting some internal class that has the following attribute

`[DataContract(IsReference = true)]`

Removing the inheritance or the attribute solved the issue :)